# Div is not centered in full width page header on IE8 only

Tags: css, html, center

I have the header div [on this page](http://www.olwan.org) floating left. It's supposed to be centered in the middle of the page.

Any idea what the problem is?, It works perfectly on Chrome, Safari and Firefox, but not IE8.

Comment: Try fixing these [validation errors](http://validator.nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.olwan.org%2F).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got IE-specific styles that turn that header into an inline-block:

```
<!--[if gte IE 7.0]>
<style type="text/css">
.clearfix {display: inline-block;}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Remove .`clearfix` from `#ja-header`

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to use the HTML5 doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>`. I recently had a problem like this and that solved it for me.